# Ubuntu Server vs Desktop for mining PC

Tags: miner-configuration, ubuntu, server, cpu-mining

Could anyone tell if `Ubuntu Server` has any advantages over `Ubuntu Desktop` for mining?

Basically, [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31081/whats-the-difference-between-the-server-version-and-the-desktop-version) is explained that there should be no big difference since that the `Server` and `Desktop` are different by initial packages installed.

I am wondering:

1. if energy can be saved as you are not using graphical environment
2. if GPU would have better performance in case it mining PC is manage
   by SSH connection against a monitor is connected to it when using
   `Ubuntu Desktop`
3. if the mining PC will work better - I noticed that some icons (like updates) are not responsive on my `Ubuntu Desktop` after 24 hours mining a

Any others pros and cons about using server versions against desktop version that anyone can share will be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would highly recommend using Ubuntu Server for this, as long as you know what you are doing without a GUI. Not having a GUI at all means smaller OS size and much less OS tasks. This translates into more power savings. If you are using graphics cards, a non-GUI OS *will* improve your mining performance. If using an ASIC/etc. you probably will not see performance improvements, but you should definitely see power consumption improvements.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wwas kind of knowing this, but need a confirmation.